# how generate random string in python

Tags: python, random

By python random.choice, I am trying to generate 30 values randomly, with two options "fruit" and "sweet". where there is a percentage:  20% as sweet and 80% as fruits

```
here is my code :
```

> ```
> repeats = 30
> fpercentage = 0.8
> spercentage = 0.2
> f  = 0 
> s = 0
>
> for i in range (repeats):
>    priority_options = {"sweet","fruit"}
>    temp = random.choice(list(priority_options))     
>    if(temp == "sweet" and (s <= (repeats * spercentage)) ):
>         print(temp)
>         s = s+1         
>    elif(temp=="fruit" and (f <= (repeats * fpercentage))):
>         print(temp)    
>         f= f+1
>    else:
>        print("here else",temp)
> ```

```
> the output   fruit fruit sweet fruit fruit fruit sweet sweet fruit
> sweet fruit sweet sweet sweet fruit here else sweet fruit fruit here
> else sweet here else sweet fruit here else sweet fruit here else sweet
> here else sweet here else sweet here else sweet fruit here else sweet
> here else sweet
```

why was the last else executed? how can I solve this problem to get exactly 20% and 80% ??

my expected output should be 30 items, each item is either "fruit" or "sweet". But the "fruit" is 80% from 30 so it will appear 24times more than "sweet" which should appear only 6 times because it's percentage is only 20%

also I have tried the following

```
    priority_options = ["sweet","fruit"]
for i in range (repeats):
    temp = random.choices(priority_options, weights=(20,80), k=1)
    if(temp == "sweet"):
            print("s",temp)
            s = s+1         
    elif(temp =="fruit"):
            print("f",temp)    
            f= f+1
    else:
           print("here else",temp)
```

The else is always executed so all the output only contains "here else",...

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output should be 30 items, each item is either "fruit" or "sweet". But the "fruit" is 80% from 30 so it will appear 24times more than "sweet" which should appear only 6 times because it's percentage is only 20%

Comment: [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)? which allow weights. `L = ['sweet', 'fruit']` and `print(choices(L, weights=[2,8], k=30))`

Comment: Or to get exactly 6 sweets and 24 fruits `L = ['sweets']*6 + ['fruits']*24` and `random.shuffle(L)`

Comment: I tried the wights but it gives me the following error :     temp = random.choices(priority_options, weights=(20,80), k=1)
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The set has to be a `list`, not a `set`

Comment: I updated my code to follow : 
for i in range (repeats):
    priority_options = ["sweet","fruit"]
    temp = random.choices(priority_options, weights=(20,80), k=1)
    if(temp == "sweet"):
            print(temp)
            s = s+1         
    elif(temp=="fruit"):
            print(temp)    
            f= f+1
    else:
           print("here else",temp)
but the output always performs the else !!!

Comment: Please keep in mind known `random` security deficiencies: if you need more reliable pseudorandom methods for cryptography-related things, use at least `secrets` builtin module.

Answer (score 1):

To spell out Chris Charley's first method, the code is:

```
import random
for i in range(30):
    L = random.choices(['sweet', 'fruit'], weights=[2, 8], k=1)[0]
    print(L)
```

First method modified to keep track of count so that a large sample can be conveniently tested:

```
import random
sweet_count = 0
fruit_count = 0

for i in range(10000000):
    L = random.choices(['sweet', 'fruit'], weights=[2, 8], k=1)[0]
    #print(L)

    if L == 'sweet':
        sweet_count += 1
    elif L == 'fruit':
        fruit_count += 1

print("Sweet count:", sweet_count)
print("Fruit count:", fruit_count)
```

Code for the second method suggested by Chris Charley:

```
import random
for i in range(30):
    L = ['sweet'] * 6 + ['fruit'] * 24
random.shuffle(L)
print(L)
```

The first method gives a random selection with 80/20 weighted chances of fruit vs sweet being selected, hence 24 and 6 won’t always be the outcome.  The second method gives a ‘shuffle’ of 24 fruits and 6 sweets, so 24 and 6 will always be the outcome.

If weights is specified in random.choices, selections are made according to relative weights, each item compared to the total, like 2/10 and 8/10.  For details on this, click on random choices in Chris Charley’s comment.

We set k=1 to indicate that we want to make a single selection in each of the 30 loops. The selected item is retrieved with [0] since random.choices returns a list of selected items, and we want the single selected item.

Your code didn't need to be so involved, it could have been just this, but it's not random after the sweets are maxed out:

```
import random
repeats = 30
fpercentage = 0.8
spercentage = 0.2
f  = 0 
s = 0

for i in range (repeats):
   priority_options = {"sweet","fruit"}
   temp = random.choice(list(priority_options))     
   if(temp == "sweet" and s <= 5):  #first time is 0
       print(temp)
       s = s+1         
   else:
       print("fruit")
       f= f+1
print(s, f)
```

Comment: The first solution works well; can you please explain to me how is that work? why [0] ? and why 8 and 2 ? rather than 0.8 or 0.2 or 2% or 8%? Is the default from 10 or what?

Comment: and why each run gives a different percentage? for example, if the total repeats is 100 it gives 17 for sweet and 83 for fruits, in another run gives 21 for sweet and 79 for fruits !!

Comment: I edited my answer to include answers to your questions.

Comment: @grald great , but why each run gives a different percentage? for example, if the total repeats is 100 it gives 17 for sweet and 83 for fruits, in another run gives 21 for sweet and 79 for fruits

Comment: In the first method the random selection is weighted 80/20, but not guaranteed to come out 80/20 every time. For example, in a random sample of coin flips there would probably not be 50 heads and 50 tails most times, but the larger the sample the closer you would get to your expectations.

Comment: I added a counter method so that you can test to your heart's content. With my 10,000,000 sample size it takes about 30 seconds to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 30 entry list with 6 sweets and 24 fruits, then pick a random sample of all 30 values.  This will always produce 20% sweets and 80% fruits:

```
import random

result = random.sample(["sweet"]*6+["fruit"]*24,30)
```

The random.sample function could also be used to pick 6 indexes to assign sweets at random positions in a list of 30 fruits (this is actually faster):

```
result = ["fruit"]*30
for i in random.sample(range(30),6):
     result[i] = "sweet"
```

To generalize this to any number of fruits and sweets, you can use variables for the multipliers and sample size:

```
total  = 30
sweets = total * 20 // 100

result = ["fruit"]*total
for i in random.sample(range(total),sweets):
    result[i] = "sweet"
```

*If you are concerned with performance, this produces the result in 3.2 seconds for 10 million items (20%/80% sweets/fruits), whereas the first random.sample solution takes 7.5 seconds.  But, if you eventually have more that two options in the list, the first approach will be much easier to use.*

The two approaches can be combined to get an even faster result while preserving the flexibility to have more than two options in the list.  Build the list with the appropriate proportion of sweets/fruits, starting with the sweets.  Then swap all the sweets with a random position in the list:

```
result = ["sweet"]*sweets+["fruit"]*(total-sweets)
for i in range(sweets):
    j = random.randrange(total)
    result[i],result[j] = result[j],result[i]
```

*This processes the 10 million item list in 2.4 seconds*

If you have more than two options, place the less frequent values at the beginning and randomly swap all but the most frequent entries.